# Copying Range into Range with merged Cells

Tags: excel, vba

i'm getting quite frustrated with this Issue after consulting Google for a few Hours.

This is my Code:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim i As Long, icount As Long
    Dim wsTo As Worksheet, wsFrom As Worksheet
    Dim src As Workbook, dest As Workbook
    Set src = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\...")
    Set dest = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsFrom = src.Worksheets("Interview Vorlage")
    Set wsTo = dest.Worksheets(ActiveSheet)

    icount = 14
    For i = 14 To 369 Step 4
        Workbooks(dest).Worksheets(wsTo).Range(Cells(9, i).Address).Value = Workbooks(src).Worksheets(wsFrom).Range(Cells(7, icount).Address)
        icount = icount + 1
    Next i

    src.Close False
    Set src = Nothing
End Sub
```

I tried the same thing with .Copy but i'm always getting a type mismatch in `Workbooks(dest).Worksheets(wsTo).Range(Cells(9, i).Address).Value = Workbooks(src).Worksheets(wsFrom).Range(Cells(7, icount).Address)`.

Would be glad if someone could help me out or point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it... You need to understand how worksheet and workbook objects work.

If you do this:
`Set wb = Workbooks("MyWorkbook.xlsx")`

Then:

`Workbooks("MyWorkbook.xlsx")` = `wb`

Same goes for a worksheet, so if you have a variable called `ws` you can do this:

`Set ws = wb.Sheets("MySheet")`

`ws.Cells(1, 2) = "Test"`

or

`Workbooks("MyWorkbook.xlsx").Sheets("MySheet").Cells(1, 2) = "Test"`

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim dest As Workbook
    Set dest = ThisWorkbook 'this is a workbook reference
    Dim wsTo As Worksheet
    Set wsTo = dest.Worksheets(ActiveSheet) 'this is a worksheet reference

    Dim src As Workbook
    Set src = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\...")
    Dim wsFrom As Worksheet
    Set wsFrom = src.Worksheets("Interview Vorlage")

    Dim icount As Long
    icount = 14

    'Now when we have everything up here defined, we can use the worksheet references,
    'because they already have a workbook reference.
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 14 To 369 Step 4
        wsTo.Cells(9, i).Value = wsFrom.Cells(7, icount).Value
        icount = icount + 1
    Next i

    src.Close False
    Set src = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped a lot.
as to: "DimwsFrom As Worksheet 'where do you use this?"
thats used in the Loop